# Rollback intelij 12 look and feel

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

The new Intellij 12 look and feel is awesome, but can it be rolled back?
I am used to the old Intellij style and icons and I really enjoyed the look and feel for the v 11.
Can I change it back somehow?

Thanks,
Arkde

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look&Feel can be changed in `File` | `Settings` | `Appearance`, editor color scheme in `File` | `Settings` | `Editor` | `Colors & Fonts`, old [icons can be restored using a plug-in](http://bulenkov.com/2012/10/10/intellij-idea-11-icons-pack-plugin/).